# Is it better to initialize semaphores in shared memory or give them as command line arguments? (C++)

Tags: design, design-patterns, c++, code-quality, semaphore

I am on a project for which I have to spawn many different processes, all in different executables, and there will be some shared memory segments and some semaphores to synchronize them. I use an "initializer" process to open some POSIX semaphores and allocate some shared memory segments.

I can not decide which is the best practice; to initialize the semaphores and load them to shared memory so everyone that acceses the memory can access them too or to pass them as command line arguments during exec?

I do not find any option better than the other, except from that the first might be redundant because the semaphores will probably never change (ID's their values will certainly change a lot) and accessing them without needing them (for some processes) is also not useful, but I have seen it happen, probably for a reason.

So I will need some reasoning for each as well.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to use the facilities that the platform offers you instead of rolling your own.

For semaphores across processes, you can use named semaphores (see the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html)) and a convention for how to call each semaphore. Then you don't need a separate process to initialize the semaphores and somehow communicate them to the other processes.